# Unusual Error appending new element to an array resulting in application crash

Tags: arrays, swift

I am fetching a list of items from an API. This works fine. I have a local variable in my view controller such that upon successfully fetch of the items from API, I am reloading my table view.

Recently in the line where I am appending contents of the array from API to my local array variable, I am now getting a crash. I have research severally on SO with no success. I keep getting the thesame error

This is code causing the crash

---

Irrelevant API fetch code

---

```
     if refresh {
                    self?.items = ticketItems
                }
                else {
                    self?.ticketItems.append(contentsOf: 
                    ticketItems)
                }
```

Usually, I should not get a crash when appending the contents of an array. This is weird to me. Please Find error message:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: !CGSizeEqualToSize(size, CGSizeZero)'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000116bb86fb __exceptionPreprocess + 331
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001157adac5 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000116bb8482 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010fe51927 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 194
    4   UIKitCore                           0x000000011e0f0399 -[_UIUpdateVisibleCellsContext addSize:forIndexPath:] + 385
    5   UIKitCore                           0x000000011e0e8643 -[UICollectionViewFlowLayout shouldInvalidateLayoutForPreferredLayoutAttributes:withOriginalAttributes:] + 409
    6   UIKitCore                           0x000000011e0a2f08 -[UICollectionView _checkForPreferredAttributesInView:originalAttributes:] + 559
    7   UIKitCore                           0x000000011e0a3c24 -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:isFocused:notify:] + 1596
    8   UIKitCore                           0x000000011e0a35e2 -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:] + 31
    9   UIKitCore                           0x000000011e0a8a8c -[UICollectionView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 6120
    10  UIKitCore                           0x000000011e0adbb6 -[UICollectionView layoutSubviews] + 365
    11  UIKitCore                           0x000000011ecf99c1 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1417
    12  QuartzCore                          0x0000000111cf7eae -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 173
    13  QuartzCore                          0x0000000111cfcb88 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 396
    14  QuartzCore                          0x0000000111d08ee4 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 72
    15  QuartzCore                          0x0000000111c783aa _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 328
    16  QuartzCore                          0x0000000111caf584 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 608
    17  QuartzCore                          0x0000000111cafede _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 76
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000116b1f0f7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000116b195be __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 430
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000116b19c31 __CFRunLoopRun + 1505
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000116b19302 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 626
    22  GraphicsServices                    0x000000011be162fe GSEventRunModal + 65
    23  UIKitCore                           0x000000011e82bba2 UIApplicationMain + 140
    24  Sterling Bank App                   0x000000010c1be211 main + 225
    25  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000118307541 start + 1
    26  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Have you enabled your exception breakpoint ? and found the exact code which cause the crash ?

Comment: Yes I have. It is still pointing to the same line of code I wrote in the question above, except maybe I did not do it correctly. Could you help further @Vicky_Vignesh

Comment: The error is completely irrelevant to your array. The exception clearly states that somewhere a `CGSize` is zero. I'm gonna guess from the stacktrace that this is a layout issue with your collectionview...

Comment: @codeperfect Can you attach a screenshot when your breakpoint is active and points the exact code ? this will surely help us !

Comment: Did you ever manage to fix this error? I'm experiencing the exact same error with an almost-identical backtrace, and I believe the issue is caused by an item in a UICollectionView having a size of `(0, 0)`.

Answer (score 5):

I was getting the exact error:

> 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: !CGSizeEqualToSize(size, CGSizeZero)'

It was just because I forgot to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false` for a subview I was adding to cell's contentView...